# Is there a "Pens" class to complement "Brushes" and "Colors" in WPF?

Tags: wpf, colors, brushes

There isn't one called `Pens`, that's for sure, but it's too odd not to find it. Is it really absent, or am I being blind?

(I'm just looking for a convenience class - for example, `Colors.Red` and `Brushes.Red` is there, but for pens the shortest appears to be `new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not the associated `Pens` class because a `Pen` is identified by both a [`Brush` and a `Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558596.aspx) rather than just one property.

If you have a need for a set of standard pens (based on some thickness) then you will have to create your own. Another approach would be to create a code generator to supply the appropriate pens.

Here is an example of a class which adds a `Pen` for each default `Brush`:

```
public class DefaultPens
{
    private Dictionary<Brush, Pen> pens;

    public double Thickness
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    // used like defaultPens[Brushes.Red]
    public Pen this[Brush brush]
    {
        get { return this.pens[brush]; }
    }

    public DefaultPens(double thickness)
    {
        this.pens = typeof(Brushes).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static)
                                   .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(Brush))
                                   .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(null, null))
                                   .ToDictionary(
                                       b => b,
                                       b => new Pen(b, thickness));
        this.Thickness = thickness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is no** `Pens` **class since it would be redundant.** (Although you're right: `Colors` and `Brushes` are somewhat redundant, too.)

Why? Well, just think about waht a pen is: its properties can be described by a stroke with (or: *thickness*) and a color (or: *brush*). Therefore, there is a [Pen Constructor(Brush, double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558596.aspx).

Comment: I think they are all exactly the same amount of redundant, namely: completely :)  There's just the convenience/verbosity aspect.